# Retrieving fasta sequences using bed file information from locally installed file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl, bioinformatics

I have a .bed file containing around 30000 rows for which I have the sequences retrieved using `fetch-sequences` module of the rsat tool (http://rsat.ulb.ac.be/rsat/help.fetch-sequences.html#usage). [Note: This tool connects to the server each time to retrieve the sequences]

Now I have about 10000 subsets of the same bed file randomly sorted for which I would like to retrieve the sequences. Using the `fetch-sequences` module, it takes 10 hours to achieve this. 
But I would like to do it quickly by first retrieving the sequences for the original file. 
Using this local file, I would like to retrieve the sequences for the subset.

Is there a way to do it using linux commands or perl? 
I am not sure how to do this with locally installed file. Please help.

Here is my sample bed file:

```
chr10   91061477    91062132    peak4069    41  .   134.220 -1  -1
chr12   77456450    77457116    peak7216    97  .   313.820 -1  -1
chr7    150754939   150755706   peak30140   87  .   281.000 -1  -1
chr3    11643031    11643625    peak20536   135 .   435.740 -1  -1
chr19   6521662 6522869 peak14719   264 .   851.950 -1  -1
chr14   35008667    35009076    peak9034    40  .   131.480 -1  -1
chr6    88851148    88852148    peak27572   55  .   178.560 -1  -1
chr6    20212045    20212627    peak26579   44  .   144.630 -1  -1
chr2    136422022   136422722   peak17485   83  .   270.330 -1  -1
chr11   45951365    45952105    peak4995    284 .   915.840 -1  -1
chr19   50181053    50181876    peak15733   101 .   328.650 -1  -1
chr9    36140202    36140695    peak32014   42  .   137.080 -1  -1
chr4    40992483    40993431    peak23120   40  .   129.060 -1  -1
chr14   50528290    50529818    peak9133    256 .   826.310 -1  -1
chr18   57542948    57543911    peak14298   244 .   789.750 -1  -1
chr21   44528945    44529572    peak19741   45  .   148.260 -1  -1
chr6    16763102    16763743    peak26552   84  .   272.680 -1  -1
chr1    44678710    44679433    peak803 97  .   312.860 -1  -1
chr12   11323475    11324633    peak6358    123 .   396.790 -1  -1
chr9    98271450    98271859    peak32325   37  .   120.160 -1  -1
chr19   2167913 2169475 peak14575   455 .   1470.150    -1  -1
chr16   80613819    80615001    peak12054   261 .   843.100 -1  -1
chr12   118574314   118574830   peak7774    43  .   141.040 -1  -1
chr19   59083917    59085058    peak15917   129 .   418.440 -1  -1
chr2    191184311   191184984   peak17942   103 .   332.220 -1  -1
chr15   85956548    85957254    peak10816   179 .   578.110 -1  -1
chr4    84031272    84032016    peak23411   60  .   195.570 -1  -1
chr12   32012425    32013045    peak6654    45  .   148.210 -1  -1
chr6    70575973    70577060    peak27441   52  .   168.800 -1  -1
chr12   57852728    57853291    peak7023    59  .   192.900 -1  -1
chr10   120879718   120880402   peak4449    209 .   675.760 -1  -1
chr1    28833424    28834023    peak526 35  .   114.020 -1  -1
chr8    60963955    60965013    peak30803   329 .   1062.570    -1  -1
chr7    77326420    77326889    peak29382   32  .   103.320 -1  -1
chr5    133476115   133476527   peak25468   37  .   121.150 -1  -1
chr19   45909117    45910074    peak15572   69  .   222.490 -1  -1
chr5    16467271    16468036    peak24373   117 .   380.290 -1  -1
chr15   66682042    66683502    peak10489   182 .   589.480 -1  -1
chr9    35603806    35604394    peak31993   71  .   229.000 -1  -1
chr4    48249067    48249653    peak23178   50  .   162.070 -1  -1
chr3    112775853   112776466   peak21577   62  .   202.250 -1  -1
chr12   12867020    12867982    peak6428    33  .   106.930 -1  -1
chr6    35655359    35655985    peak27066   53  .   171.010 -1  -1
chr6    74171305    74172116    peak27466   161 .   521.390 -1  -1
chr11   12195905    12196539    peak4741    256 .   826.330 -1  -1
chr2    55386393    55386871    peak16583   40  .   131.810 -1  -1
chr9    37030245    37030957    peak32041   89  .   290.090 -1  -1
chr4    30431566    30431997    peak22948   66  .   214.250 -1  -1
chr10   16612633    16613149    peak3304    49  .   160.900 -1  -1
```

Here is the sample of my fetched fasta sequences (for the first 3 rows in sample file above):

```
>hg19_chr10_91061478_91062132_+ range=chr10:91061478-91062132 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
AATTGTATTACAAGTCCCCAACTTAATCTTTTCGAATATGAAATAAGAGAGGGACAGTGCACAAGAGCAATGTCCCCAGACCCATCTTTAAGTGAAGCACCAGGCCGATGAAACATCCCTCTCTGCTGCCTTCTTTCTCTGATCACAACTCAGCTCCGGAGGAAAAAGAGTCCTCTAAAGTATAATAAAAAGAAAAAAAGAAAAAGAGTCCTGCCAATTTCACTTTCTAGTTTCACTTTCCCTTTTGTAACGTCAGCTGAAGGGAAACAAACAAAAAGGAACCAGAGGCCACTTGTATATATAGGTCTCTTCAGCATTTATTGGTGGCAGAAGAGGAAGATTTCTGAAGAGTGCAGCTGCCTGAACCGAGCCCTGCCGAACAGCTGAGAATTGCACTGCAACCATGAGGTAAATATTTTCCCTTCGTATTCGGTAGTGCTGTTGAGTCATCTTGTCCAATGCAAATCCTGAGAAGCTATGTTCCCAAAGAGGGCCAGCTCCATTTTAGTGTTTGTTTATAGCCTTACTATGCCTCTACCTCTGTTGGTTGTAAATCTGTCTTACCAATGGTGGTTTGTTCCCTCCTGAACAATTTTCTGCTTCACACTGGCAAGCTTCCTAAATTCATCTCCAGAACTGCACGCCTGGGGAGTTG
>hg19_chr12_77456451_77457116_+ range=chr12:77456451-77457116 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GTCTTTGTTGAAGGTACTTGATAAAAGTCATTGACCCAGAGGAAGAGAAGTAAAGCACTGACTTAGACGTTATATAAATGTATGGATGTGTATTTTTTCAAGGCTGAACCATCCAAATTGGAAAGGAAAACAAAGTTTTGCTCTAAAACTCTCAAAGCCAAAACTCTGAATATATACTTTAAGTCTGGGCATTTCCACCCTCATGACTTAGATAATTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGCCACTTTAAATAATCTTCACTTTATCTGTGGTTTCACTTTCAGTGGCCAACTGCGGTCCAAAAATATCACATGGAAAATTCCAGAAATAAACAATTCATGAGTTTTAGATTGTGTGCAGTTCTGTGTAATGAAATCTCACGTCATCCTGCTCCGTCCTGCTTCGGATGTGACTCACCCCTTTGTCCAGCGTATTTGCACGGTAGATACTACCTGCTCGAGCAGCCACTGTGTTTTCAGGCTGGCTGTCACGGTATTGCAGTGCTCATGTTCGAGTAACTCTTATTTGACTTCATAATGGCTCCAAAGCACAAGAGTAGTGATGCTGGCAATTTGGATATGCCAAAGGGAAGCCATAAAGTGCTTCTTTTAAGTGAAAAGGTGAACGTTCTTGACTTAAGGAAAGAAAATCGTACGCCAAGGTTGCTAAGAT
>hg19_chr7_150754940_150755706_+    range=chr7:150754940-150755706 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GCGGCCGCGGGGACCCCTGCGGGCCCTCGGTTTTAAGACTCTGGCCCCGGCGTTGCAGAGGAGGCGGCACCTGAGCCTCCAGCCCCGCCCCGTCTGCCCGCGCAGGGCCTTCTGGGGCTTGTAGTCCTAAAACGACTAGGTCTCCCCGCAATGCCCGAGACCGAGGACAAGAAGACTACAACCCCCAGCCGTCTGCGCTCACGCTCTCTGCAGCACTCGACTCCAGGGCTCCGTTTCTACCGCGGAGGCAAACCTTGGACTTCAAGTCCCAGGAAGCAACGCGTGTCCGTTTTCCGGGCGCCCCGCCGCGGCGCCGTGGTTCCCAGTGTGCCCCGCTGTTGTTATTCCTTTTATGTGCTCCCAGCCCTCTTGAAAAGGGCCGCTCCGGGACTACGCGTTCCAGAATGCAGCGGAAATGGGGGCGGAGCGCTCTCGGTTAGGGGTTTGGGGTTTGGCGGCCTAGATCCCGGGCACTGGCGGCCCAGCGCTGACCTGGTTGGTGGCATTGTGTTCCCAACGGCCTCTTGACGACCTCAGCACGGGTTTCCACCTCTCCCCAAGCCACCTAGTGACCCCAGAATTGACTGGGGAATGCCTGTGAGCGATGATGACCTCACAGGGAACAGCTGACCGCAGGGCTGGGAGAACAGCTGTGCCCCTTCGAGGCTGGATTTTAGTGGAGGGACACACGCCAAAGACCCCCTCTCTGCTGAGCCCCGTTTGTTGTCTCGGAGCCCACCCGACTCTAGCCGCTGAACTCTGACATG
```

Comment: Do you mean getting 10000 subset randomly from 30000 rows?

Comment: Yes, @Gnouc...!!

Comment: What format are your sequences in? Fasta? Tbl? Flat files? How are the sequences named? We can't help unless we know the format of your input file. Please provide us with a minimal example of what you need.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing, or will you be doing this regularly? If the latter, then consider using a proper database. It should be quite fast. I recommend PostgreSQL.

Comment: @terdon: I have edited my question now

Comment: And are all sequences in the same file? It looks like each sequence range in the file starts at n+1 with respect to the coordinates in the .bed file, is that correct? Is that the actual format of your file? Is the sequence always on a single line or is it normal FASTA (60 nt per line)?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I would like to do this for 150 of my datasets. Also, i have no experience in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, all sequences are in same file. I wouldn#t mind running it once for the entire bed file. But my problem is I need to retrieve it for 10000 subsets of the same bed file. 
It always gets retrieved that way (n-1) on a single line

Comment: @biobudhan If you are doing bioinformatics, you will probably want to learn how to use a proper database sooner or later. I'd recommend sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
for i in $(awk '{print $1"_"$2+1"_"$3}' foo.bed); do grep -A 1 $i seqs.fa ; done
```

#### Explanation

- `awk '{print $1"_"$2+1"_"$3}' foo.bed` : this will print the chromosome and start and end coordinates for each line of the .bed file. Note the `$2+1`, since the coordinates in your file are different to those of the `.bed`. For example, for the first three lines of your file:

  ```
  $ awk '{print $1"_"$2+1"_"$3}' foo.bed 
  chr10_91061478_91062132
  chr12_77456451_77457116
  chr7_150754940_150755706
  ```
- `for i in $(command); do ...; done` : this will save each value returned by `command` as `$i` and then do something with it.
- `grep -A 1 $i seqs.fa` : this is the "something". It will grep for each result of the `awk` command and print the matching line as well as the next one (`-A 1`).

---

If you ever need to do this again, don't use RSAT!<sup>1</sup> There are much simpler ways of doing this. Instead, download the FASTA sequences of each chromosome and then use the tools from the `exonerate` package (installable on Debian based systems with `sudo apt-get install exonerate`). The procedure (assuming you have a FASTA file for each chromosome named `chrN.fa`) would be:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,($3-$2)}' foo.bed | while read chr start length; do
    fastasubseq /path/to/$chr.fa $start $length >> subseqs.fa
done
```

The command above will extract the subsequences of interest (assuming the coordinates are always with respect to the plus strand as they should be) and should only take a few seconds.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Don't get me wrong, the RSAT suite is a great tool and I have a lot of respect for its author with whom I have worked for a few years, it's just not necessarily the best tool for such large scale jobs.</sub>

Comment: I tried the first approach with:
`for i in $(awk '{print $1"_"$2+1"_"$3}' foo.bed); do grep -A 1 $i seqs.fa > subset.fa ; done
but only the last sequence is printed in the output file. But if I display it on the screen I can see all the sequences for my subset

Comment: @biobudhan that's because `>` overwrites the file and only the last seq will be kept. Use `>>` instead: `for i in $(); do grep -A 1 $i seqs.fa >> subseq.fa ; done` or put the redirection after the loop: `for i in $(); do grep -A 1 $i seqs.fa; done > subset.fa `